# Can't zip Python tuples to get plot axes values

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, python-3.5

I want to unzip the tuple for X, Y values of my plot, and it gives me an error if the items inside the new tuple are composed of 3 components ('AXIN', 37, 'reported'), instead of 2 (AXIN, 37).

Error says to many values to unpack

```
new = (('AXIN', 37, 'reported'),
 ('LGR', 30, 'reported'),
 ('NK', 24, 'reported'),
 ('TN', 23, 'reported'),
 ('CC', 19, 'reported'),
 ('APC', 18, 'reported'),
 ('TRD@', 16, 'reported'),
 ('TOX', 15, 'UNREPORTED'), 
 ('LEF', 15, 'reported'),
 ('MME', 13, 'reported'),
 ('NOTUM', 13, 'reported'),
 ('PLCB', 13, 'UNREPORTED'), 
 ('GN', 11,  'UNREPORTED'),
 ('LOX', 10,  'UNREPORTED'),
 ('LOX', 10, 'reported'),
 ('CRND', 10, 'reported'),
 ('LRP', 9, 'reported'),
 ('BMP', 9, 'reported'),
 ('VSNL', 8,  'UNREPORTED'),
 ('LOC', 8, 'reported'),
 ('ZNRF', 8, 'reported'),
 ('KRT', 8,  'UNREPORTED'),
 ('CTNN', 8, 'reported'))


X, Y = zip(*new)
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
%matplotlib inline
plt.figure(figsize = (20, 10))
mytitle = "Most common genes coexpressed with {gene1}, {gene2}, {gene3}, {gene4}".format(gene1="axin2", gene2="lef", gene3="nkd1", gene4="lgr5")
plt.title(mytitle, fontsize=40)
plt.ylabel('Number of same gene encounters across studies', fontsize=20)
ax = plt.bar(range(len(X)), Y, 0.6, align='center', tick_label = X, color="green") 
ax = plt.xticks(rotation=90)
new = tuple(new)
import networkx as nx
children = sorted(new, key=lambda x: x[1])
parent = children.pop()[0]

G = nx.Graph()
for child, weight in children: G.add_edge(parent, child, weight=weight)
width = list(nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight').values())
colors = []
for i in new:
        if i[2] == 'UNREPORTED':
                colors.append('green')
        elif i[2] == 'REPORTED':
                colors.append('yellow')
nx.draw_networkx(G, font_size=10, node_size=2000, alpha=0.6, node_color=colors)
plt.savefig("plt.gene-expression.pdf")
plt.figure(figsize = (20, 10))
mytitle = "Most common genes coexpressed with {gene1}, {gene2}, {gene3}, {gene4}".format(gene1="axin2", gene2="lef", gene3="nkd1", gene4="lgr5")
plt.title(mytitle, fontsize=40)
nx.draw_networkx(G, font_size=10, node_size=2000, alpha=0.6)  #width=width is very fat lines
plt.savefig("gene-expression-graph.pdf")
```

`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true, there are too many values to unpack. You have only given two variables to unpack into, but there are three values per tuple. Try giving it another variable:

```py
X, Y, Notes = zip(*new)
```

Now it's unpacked properly. If you don't want to use the third component, you can give it a variable name you never use. Or use `_`, which by convention in Python means "nevermind" or "don't care":

```py
X, Y, _ = zip(*new)
```

My only reservation about this convention is that in interactive use (e.g. IPython, Jupyter Notebook, or the stock Python interactive REPL), `_` also means "the last value produced." That sometimes conflicts with the "don't care" interpretation.

You will, btw, need to use the same trick lower in your code as well, which has the same "wrong number of items to unpack" problem:

```py
for child, weight, _ in children:
    ...
```

Those changes made, out pop the charts:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.

Why it shows the green and red nodes separately, not  together in the same 1 big graph below?

Comment: Because of where you have your  `plt.figure(...)` calls relative to your `nx.draw_networkx(...)` calls. If you want to combine the graphs in a single image, put one (and just one) `plt.figure(...)` before any of the `nx.draw_networkx(...)` graphs. [example output](https://screencast.com/t/6AAdzWu5tP2c). For better graph layout, however, you need just one graph draw...which will mean reorganizing your code more extensively.